# Permutating a vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, permutation

I am trying to get every permutation of a vector but also with a divider that indicates sub-permutations. It seems there is a mistake in my code as you can see from my results the ending permutation.

`0 1 3 2 |` and `0 2 3 1 |` and `0 3 2 1 |` are all duplicated.

I am also curious if there is a way to do what I am trying to do that can accept a reference to the vector rather than making a copy.

IDEONE: http://ideone.com/fork/2v0wk3

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void permute(vector<int> v, int path_length) {
    do {
        for(int i=0; i<=3; ++i) {
            cout << v[i] << " ";
            if(i == path_length-1)
            cout << "| ";
        }
        cout << endl;

        if(path_length == v.size()) {
            cout << "====="<< endl;
            return;
        }

        permute(v, path_length+1);
    } while(next_permutation(v.begin()+path_length-1,v.end()));
}

int main() {
    vector<int> v;

    for(int i=0;i<=3;++i)
        v.push_back(i);

    int path_length = 2;
    permute(v, path_length);
    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
0 1 | 2 3 
0 1 2 | 3 
0 1 2 3 | 
=====
0 1 3 | 2 
0 1 3 2 | 
=====
0 1 | 3 2 
0 1 3 | 2 
0 1 3 2 | 
=====
0 2 | 1 3 
0 2 1 | 3 
0 2 1 3 | 
=====
0 2 3 | 1 
0 2 3 1 | 
=====
0 2 | 3 1 
0 2 3 | 1 
0 2 3 1 | 
=====
0 3 | 1 2 
0 3 1 | 2 
0 3 1 2 | 
=====
0 3 2 | 1 
0 3 2 1 | 
=====
0 3 | 2 1 
0 3 2 | 1 
0 3 2 1 | 
=====
```

Expected Results:

```
0 1 | 2 3 
0 1 2 | 3 
0 1 2 3 | 
=====
0 1 3 | 2 
0 1 3 2 | 
=====
0 2 | 1 3 
0 2 1 | 3 
0 2 1 3 | 
=====
0 2 3 | 1 
0 2 3 1 | 
=====
0 3 | 1 2 
0 3 1 | 2 
0 3 1 2 | 
=====
0 3 2 | 1 
0 3 2 1 | 
=====
```

Comment: So basically, you expected to see the vector "v" declared in your main() function to have changed values after permute( ) is called?  Or even more to the point, did you expect that "v" parameter to be changed after permute() is called recursively?

Comment: I am more interested in the permutations that are created in order to do branch and bound algo on an optimal TSP problem. The int of vectors represent index of vertices in a graph. The divider demostrates the division between vertices in the solution (left) and vertices that need to have a cost-estimate. The idea being I can skip a permutation if min-cost > lowerbound

Comment: Are you sure that the issue isn't that you're passing the vector `by value` instead of `by reference`?  That passing of the vector by value just looks suspicious to me.  All of those changes that next_permutation() is doing is lost as soon as permute() returns.

Comment: This is part of the solution/problem by just doing by reference results in an infinite loop so that's the issue I am having trouble with. I want it to pass by reference in the first call so that `0 1 | 2 3` begins at `0 2 | 1 3 ` after `0 1 3 2 |` but on the other calls I don't want it by reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider another way to generate every sequence you need.
We will have a `vector <int> cur` to store the current sequence, and a `vector <bool> used` to track which integers are used and which are not.
In a recursive function with a `depth` argument, find another unused integer, put it as `cur[depth]` and proceed considering the next position, which is `depth + 1`.
Print the result anytime the depth is in the required bounds.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int const n = 3;

void generate (vector <int> & cur, vector <bool> & used, int depth) {
    if (depth >= 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
            cout << cur[i] << ' ';
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        if (!used[i]) {
            used[i] = true;
            cur[depth] = i;
            generate (cur, used, depth + 1);
            used[i] = false;
        }
    }
}

int main () {
    vector <int> cur (n);
    vector <bool> used (n, false);
    cur[0] = 0;
    used[0] = true;
    generate (cur, used, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
0 1 
0 1 2 
0 1 2 3 
0 1 3 
0 1 3 2 
0 2 
0 2 1 
0 2 1 3 
0 2 3 
0 2 3 1 
0 3 
0 3 1 
0 3 1 2 
0 3 2 
0 3 2 1
```

You can add the `=====` part, too, if you print it when `depth > n`.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted but close enough I could work with. I had a need for the remaining values that were right of my divider.

Comment: @BHare: if you do not need to consider their order, they can be restored by just looping over the `used` array and seeing which ones are not used.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear to me. You can use the not so well known [next permutation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) from the STL :

```
std::vector<int> my_vector = { 1 , 5 , 7 , 2 , 3 , 10};
std::sort(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end());
do {
    std::copy(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end(), ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
} while(std::next_permutation(my_vector.begin(), my_vector.end()));
```

1 - Sort the vector
2 - Iterate over the permutations
(the do while just print it with a copy to the cout)

I'm not wure of what you call "sub" permutations, are you just moving the "|" inside each permutation ?

Comment: Note that (1) the code from the question _does_ use `next_permutation` and (2) the desired output is different than just all permutations. Rather, it is all ordered collections of {1,2,3} with 0 prepended.